# JQuery UI Autocomplete Syntax

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Can someone help me understand the following code? I found it [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote).

It takes advantage of the JQuery UI Autocomplete with a remote source. I've commented the code as best I can and a more precise question follows it.

```
    $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response )  {
//request is an objet which contains the user input so far
// response is a callback expecting an argument with the values to autocomplete with
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON", //where is script located 
                dataType: "jsonp", //type of data we send the script
                data: { //what data do we send the script 
                    featureClass: "P",
                    style: "full",
                    maxRows: 12,
                    name_startsWith: request.term
                },
                success: function( data ) { //CONFUSED!
                    response( 
                        $.map( 
                        data.geonames, function( item ) { 
                                            return {
                                                    label: item.name+(item.adminName1 ? ","+item.adminName1:"")+","+item.countryName,   
        value: item.name
                                            }
                                        }
                        )
                    );
                  }
            });
        }
    });
```

As you can see, I don't understand the use of the success function and the response callback.

I know the success function literal is an AJAX option which is called when the AJAX query returns. In this case, it seems to encapsulate a call to the response callback? Which is defined where? I thought by definition of a callback, it should be called on its own?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `response` object as defined by the documentation ("Overview" page):

> A response callback, which expects a
>   single argument to contain the data to
>   suggest to the user. This data should
>   be filtered based on the provided
>   term, and can be in any of the formats
>   described above for simple local data
>   (String-Array or Object-Array with
>   label/value/both  properties). It's
>   important when providing a custom
>   source callback to handle errors
>   during the  request. You must always
>   call the response callback even if you
>   encounter an error. This ensures  that
>   the widget always has the correct
>   state.

so, the 'response' argument is actually a callback, which must be called upon success of the ajax retrieval of autocomplete items.

Since your data will come back via AJAX, your code must update the widget manually.  jQueryUI provides an argument as a function so that your code can do that update by calling the function.

You can see the `response` object defined in the declaration of the function used for the `source` option:

```
source: function( request, response )
```

You could even take the AJAX call out of the equation and do something like this:

```
source: function(request, response) {
    response([{label:'foo', value: 'foo'},{label:'bar', value:'bar'}]);
}
```

Would immediately call the `response` callback with an array of label/value pairs for the widget.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. But I thought by definition of a callback, it doesn't need to be called, but rather is automatically called for you at the completion of its parent function? (This understanding was influenced by http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#Callback_and_Functions )

Comment: @djs22: Right--Except in this case, jQuery is providing *you* a callback *that you need to call* with data that the autocomplete widget expects. (just like jQuery does with callbacks you provide like in the examples on the page you linked)

Comment: @djs22: Think of it this way: The autocomplete widget needs to be told when to update, since you're using an ajax call.  The way that autocomplete makes this happen is by providing you a function to call whenever you're ready to update the widget (after you've received data via AJAX `success` and formatted it).

Comment: Great! That explains it perfectly. For future reference, do you know how I can tell the difference between a callback as I described and one as you described?

Comment: @djs22: Usually, documentation will help you.  When *you're* defining the function, its a callback that you've supplied (as you described).  When a callback is passed to you, it'll usually be a function parameter (as I've described).